# How to use TinyMCE plugin in Plone using Products.TinyMCE?

Tags: javascript, tinymce

I have just packaged my plugin for TinyMCE to distribute it along with Plone.

But how to tell TinyMCE in Plone to use my plugin? I checked site setup / addons / tinymce - there are some options for buttons, styles etc - but I don't see anything related with plugins.

How to configure it using Plone, not plain TinyMCE.

Answer (score -2):

To use a plug-in with tinymce just add it to the init:

```
  tinyMCE.init({
    theme : "advanced",
    elements: "ta",
    mode : "textareas",
    plugins : "ibrowser", //plug-in list
    theme_advanced_buttons3_add : "ibrowser"
  });
```

Comment: I gave "-" because it was mentioned, that question is for Plone layer.